# Python 3.4 Django 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'

Tags: django, python-3.4

I am trying to run through the POST dictionary but for some reason when I run my code with python 3.4 instead of python 2.7 I run into a `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'` error. Here is the code I am running:

```
def printKeys(request):
    for a in sorted(request.POST.iterkeys()):
        print(a)
```

Comment: If the answer helped, you should considering giving the love!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume that `QueryDict` is a subclass of the built-in `dict`. Dictionaries do not have `.iterkeys` (neither `.itervalues` or `.iteritems`) on python 3.x. The methods `.keys`, `.values`, `.items` return directly an iterable view of the underlying dictionary rather than constructing (possibly) expensive lists.

If you want to construct a list out of those, you have to do it explicitly:

```
keys = list(request.POST.keys())
```

or more succinctly, you can just pass the dict to `list`, since the dictionaries are iterated per default on the keys.

```
keys = list(request.POST)
```

However, you can call sorted directly on an iterable, so this is just fine:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(request.POST)
```

Your function can be rewritten as:

```
def print_keys(request):
   print('\n'.join(sorted(request.POST)))
```

And this should work on both python 2.7 and 3.4.